# Fetch web page manually with socket and ssl

Tags: python, http, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to fetch a web page using the low-level [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and [`ssl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) libraries.

My current code is based on the first example from the [ssl library's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#socket-creation). After creating an SSL socket, I send a handwritten `GET` request and read the response:

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'www.python.org'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        request = f'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {hostname}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
        ssock.sendall(request.encode())

        response = b''
        while True:
            chunk = ssock.recv(4096)
            if not chunk:
                break
            response += chunk

        print(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

[www.python.org](http://www.python.org) works fine but most of the time something goes wrong when I try to fetch one of the top 10 web pages from Wikipedia's [List of most visited websites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_visited_websites). Since the returned HTTP status code is often `302 Found` telling me something like

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser
```

I tried replacing `www.facebook.com` with `https://www.facebook.com` in the `GET` request:

```
request = f'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: https://{hostname}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
```

Now, I get different status codes like:

```
400 Bad Request
500 Internal Server Error
```

What I would like to achieve is pretty much what the following code does.

```
import requests

url = 'https://python.org'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

Notes:

- I don't necessarily need a secure connection but without `ssl` I had even less success.
- I don't want to use this in production.

Comment: *...but most of the time something goes wrong...* nothing has gone wrong, it's just that HTTP is more complicated protocol than you are prepared to implement. The examples on the ssl documentation are just a demonstration. They are in no way, shape, or form pretending to be a full-featured HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Facebook is obviously it is expecting a User-Agent header, which browsers normally include with a request. Since you are not a browser, you need to at least pretend that you are by including that.

Probably your best bet if you are going to expect to submit requests using just a socket, but get back the same kinds of responses that browsers get, is to submit the request first through a browser and look at the headers that are sent and returned by each of the sites you're interested in (use the browser's own development tools for that). Then just add any and all headers that look like they are expected by a site to your own requests.